# Rename references at the same time in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, package

I have the following situation:
Consider that I have a class nested in a folder structure like for example `/fol/der/exam/ple.java` . Of course, the class ple.java contains package or import instuctions referencing to some sources. Now, when I choose `Use as a source folder` for `/fol/der/exam/ple.java` then, of course, the references used in package, import or function parameters are not the same anymore. I need to adjust them. Is there an elegant how to do that automatically in eclipse?

So, let´s assume that I have the following line in `ple.java`:

```
package fol.der.exam;
```

and that I have this line also in other files like a.java, b.java, etc. and I want to change the line, let´s say to `package der.exam;` 
How can I do that automatically for all java files in eclipse?

best regards,

Comment: Are you asking how to move a Java class from one package to another? If so, then just drag and drop the file from one package to another. Or right-click, choose Refactor - Move.

Comment: I have a certain folder structure in my project. In one of the 'normal' folders, I have generated classes with package declarations and other references. Now, I need to use this 'normal' folder as 'source' folder. Therefore, I click on "Use as source folder". When I do that, then the whole content goes to a newly created source folder(as I wish), but the problem is that the package declarations and other referencing stuff is not correct anymore and they need to be updated. To do this manually takes a lot of time.

Comment: I can't understand anything do you understand that source folders MUST be the root of a package tree? I.e. if there is a file named `foo/bar/Baz.java` under the source folder `mySrc`, then Baz MUST be in the package foo.bar. And neither `foo` nor `bar` should be source folders, since they wouldn't contain a package tree root. It's quite simple: you choose source folders, and the java files inside must be organized by strictly respecting the package organization.

Comment: now, I understand. My mistake was to choose folders like foo. For that reason it not worked